# Flask SQLAlchemy initial database connection extremely slow

Tags: python, sql-server, flask, iis, sqlalchemy

When I make an initial database connection with FlaskSQLAlchemy it is extremely slow, sometimes taking a minute or more to successfully connect and execute a query. Any subsequent database calls after the initial connection are fast. From my understanding this has something to do with "lazy loading". How can I "force" this initial connection to occur earlier, or speed up the connection altogether?

I am using MS SQL Server for my database, and pyodbc for my DB API. The application is deployed on Windows IIS server, although this problem occurs even while connecting locally - it is exacerbated while deployed on IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Use latest version of PYODBC driver. First install python package.

```
pip install pyodbc
```

If you use following code, then you will get fast Response from MSSQL database for sure.

```
import urllib
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(
    'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=server-name;DATABASE=database-name;UID=sa;PWD=****;Trusted_Connection=yes;'
)

class Config:
    DEBUG = True
    SECRET_KEY = "E9738F40-4210ACAD94B"
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params
```

Make sure your ODBC driver is accurate in your system. If you want to get knowledge about ODBC driver, then run following query in cmd command.

```
import pyodbc
pyodbc.drivers()
```

Then put following code in your **init**.py file

```
def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)
```

Above things will be giving your ORM (Object Relation Mapper) which will gives you a technique of mapping object parameters to the underlying RDBMS table structure. An ORM API provides methods to perform CRUD operations without having to write raw SQL statements.

Comment: I am currently connecting similarly to that but my SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI looks more like this `mssql+pyodbc://user:pass@server:1433/DatabaseName?driver=SQL+Server` What is the difference between that and using `"mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params` ?

Comment: I believe, mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params  This line of code build formatted connection string.